# function within function js

Tags: javascript, function, nested, closures

I'm trying to create a function that will remove first and last character from a string. Im converting the string into an array, and then I want to use shift() and pop() methods to remove the characters.

I seem to have a trouble with passing the `splitStr` variable that has array within to another function that will pop/shift the character.

What am I doing wrong?

```
let str = 'example';

let removeChar = function(str){
      let splitStr = str.split("");

      function popLast(splitStr){
        let popStr = splitStr.pop();
      }

      function shiftFirst(splitStr){
        let shiftStr = splitStr.shift();

      }

}

removeChar(str);
```

Comment: You're neither returning any value from your function nor use it at call.

Comment: what are you trying to do split then pop then shift it then return or are you wanting to return a function?

Comment: what is your expected outcome

Comment: Well, you're not invoking popLast() and siftFirsst() anywhere

Comment: @mino hope my answer helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're not exicuting your functions just creating a function called popLast and shiftFirst the calls are happening within the function but are never called.

> create a function that will remove first and last character from a string
>
> ```js
> let str = 'example';
>
> let removeChar = function(str){
>       let splitStr = str.split("");
>       splitStr.pop();
>       splitStr.shift();
>       return splitStr.join("")
> }
>
>
> console.log(removeChar(str));
> ```

but this isn't the best way to remove first and last letters from a string for that we can use splice()

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

```js
function removeChar(string) {
   return string.slice(1, -1);
}
console.log(removeChar("example"));
```

I'd suggest reading about the return keyword

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Comment: Thank you for your time, this explains a lot!

Comment: any questions let me know feel like you know what you need to do but just fuzzy about details.  break your problems down make it work then find better ways chances are the first way you do it is wrong but thats fine we're trying to understand first